# Can Maven specify different dependencies for different modules in a war?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Apologize if you cannot understand my question by the question title but let me elaborate more:

I have a **Project A** which I use maven to create a war file. Project A depends on another **Project B**. The project B is an old project and it tightly depends on **hibernate 3**. Project A is the one what I am currently working on and I would like its code use **Hibernate 4**. I add Hibernate 4 dependency into project A's maven POM file so in the generated WAR file, I have both hibernate 3 and Hibernate 4 jars.

However when I launch project A, the hibernate 3 code is always automatically used by code in project A.

The result I am after is that code in project A uses hibernate 4 jar automatically while hibernate 3 jar is still included and used by code of project B.

Can I use **Maven** to achieve this? or what tools to use to do this?

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I don't think this is a maven question but a java one. Maven is just a tool to build/package your application, but the behavior that you are trying to achieve is java specific

Answer (score 1):

if you bundle B inside A with its dependencies, at runtime it will scan classpath from start to end and it will pickup first version of class whichever comes first, so if you put 3 ahead in classpath hibernate 3 will get picked up, ignoring 4,

in short update code to use latest version

Comment: Thanks @Jigar for reply. I changed the order of dependency in my pom file so that the hibernate 4 should be before the hibernate 3 in the classpath. but the hibernate 3 code is still loaded and executed...

Comment: Make your code to expect only one version availabke at runtime and compile tjme